# How to search with option value in select using select2 or any other js

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I am looking some help on how to search with option value instead of option name.

Here is the example:

```
<select name="example" id="example">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
    <option value="6">F</option>    
</select>
```

I want to search with value 1 or 2 or 3 etc not with the A,B,C,D,E..

Any help in this regard is much appriciated or any library which has such functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result of fetching the `select` value with [**addEventListener()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) using pure javascript with single line expression like,

```js
const select = document.getElementById('example');
select.addEventListener('change',() => console.log(select.value))
```

```html
<select name="example" id="example">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
    <option value="6">F</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should listen to the event on the change of `example`
2. You get the value of the selected option like below

```js
$("#example").on("change", function(){
    var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    console.log(value); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="example" id="example">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
        <option value="5">E</option>
        <option value="6">F</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Deepak Lakhara